# Why the exception class created cannot run in the raiser function

Tags: python, class, exception, error-handling, raise

Can anyone let me know why the exception class I created cannot run in the raiser function?

```
class E3Exception(Exception):
  pass

class E3OddException(E3Exception):
  pass

def raiser (x):
  if (int(x)%2==1):
    raise E3OodException
  elif (int(x)%2==0):
    raise E3Exception
  elif x=='CSC148':
    e.message=+'Hi,Brian'
  elif (x==str & int(x)!=int):
    raise ValueError
  elif (x!=str & x!=int):
    raise TypeError
```

Thanks

Comment: Be more specific: what error do you get? Post the stack trace. Your code contains multiple typos, though.

Comment: You wrote "Ood" instead of "Odd", and the line `e.message=+'Hi,Brian'` makes no sense, as there is no variable `e` in your code (and `=+` is another typo)

Comment: When I tried raiser(3) it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 9, in raiser
builtins.NameError: name 'E3OodException' is not defined

Comment: when I tried raiser(4) it shows Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in raiser
__main__.E3Exception:

Comment: Ok, so `raiser(3)` fails because of one of those typos I just mentioned, and it looks like `raiser(4)` works fine, right?

Comment: If you think there's a problem when you run `raiser(4)`, please explain in more detail. To an outsider it looks like it worked fine: the name of the function is *"raiser"*, and it *raised the exception*.

Comment: Oh I did not know if it raised it...if it has it s great, that s what I am looking for...thanks

Comment: You can see by looking at the last line of the stack trace. It says what the exception was there.

Comment: Hi I change my code to the following class E3Exception(Exception):
    pass
    
class E3OddException(E3Exception):
    pass
    
def raiser (x):
    if (int(x)%2==1):
        raise E3OddException
    elif (int(x)%2==0):
        x=int(x)
    elif (x=='CSC148'):
        raise E3Exception
    elif (x!='CSC148' & x==str & int(x)!=int):
        raise ValueError
    else:
        raise TypeError    however, CSC148 still bring me to Value Error and I could not understand why that would happen

Comment: You can see why by looking at your stack trace, again. I'm sure it says that the value error is on the first `if` line, and happens because `'CSC148'` is not a base 10 integer. Well, that's true. If you do `int(x)` and `x` is a string that's not an integer, it'll throw a `ValueError`.

Comment: If you manage to get your final two `elif`s to run, you'll probably notice that they're wrong, also. That's not how you check types in Python: you're probably looking for the `isinstance` method. A better way to test Python's behavior for simple cases like this is to play around in the interactive interpreter. You could try all sorts of comparison tests and see what they'll do.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the isinstance method, that helps alot. I am new to python and used to use C# so that s probably my syntax is a little messy